# Float left element and float right element get pushed up by a heading (chrome)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div floating left, another div floating right and a div containing a heading in the middle, when the page gets narrow and the div in the middle gets pushed down, which is expected but it also pushes the left and right divs above and over the container which is the problem.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3rnjq0vb/ , you need to resize the preview to see the problem

it seems to be working as expected on edge and fire

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 50px;
    width: 700px;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="center">
        <h2>Some-text</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like as the viewport gets narrower? Is the 'some-text' element always to remain between the tomato and cyan elements i.e. the tomato is to the left, the some-text (maybe) on the same line and the cyan on a new line,, or do tomato and cyan stay on the same line as long as possible with some-text dropping down?

Comment: @AHaworth I should have probably included a screenshot.

What I want: (mozilla) https://imgur.com/a/nJHiudk
What I get: (chrome) https://imgur.com/a/GW6koaM Left and right get pushed up out of container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug only on chrome & opera. In this case If an inline-block component has height bigger than the component floating to the left it's going to push the floating elements out of the container for some reason.

My hacky solution at the moment is to lower height of the inline element https://jsfiddle.net/4ud7vemL/

```
    <div class="center">
        <h2 class="center-text">Some-text</h2>
    </div>
```

```
.center-text {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is give the central element a specific width - the width of the container less the width of the other two elements, and float it also.

```
width: calc(100% - 900px);
```

It will need to have a minimum width set else it will get squashed out of existence when the viewport is narrowed.

Here's a snippet:

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
  width: 700px;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 900px);
  min-width: 150px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">
    <h2>Some-text</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

For a more responsive approach - where for example the widths of the two side elements change as the viewport changes, you could investigate grid or flex depending on exactly what outcome you want on narrower viewports.

Answer (score 0):

Floats should not be used for layout anymore (though you can still use them for the original purpose - floating text around images). Flexbox is now widely supported and is better for layout.

**Try this**
HTML --->

```
<div class ="wrapper">
 <div class="left">left</div>  
 <div class="center">
        <h2>Some-text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Then add css->

```
    .left {
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.right {
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 50px;
    width: 700px;
}

.center {
    height: auto;
    width:200px;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}
```